# .js files and the jQuery AJAX Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, stringify

If I have the following .js file, how do I call it using a jQuery AJAX method? I am familiar with using JSON files, but this is both a .js file and has similar syntax to a JSON file so it has me confused. Is the JSON.stringify() method part of the solution? While this is just sample code, I am ultimately trying to create separate arrays based on age, but that should not affect the original question.

```
these_records = [
  {
    "name": "sarah",
    "age": "50"
  },
  {
    "name": "mary",
    "age": "40"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for jQuery. No need for Ajax. Just load it and use it.

```
<script src="records.js"></script>
<script>
    alert(these_records[0].name);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but like Plummer mentioned, I am using temporary model data so I wanted to use an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the only reason you'd do this is if you were using a temporary model data in place of an API service.

You should still be able to access the contents of the file through AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "path/to/file.js",
  dataType: "script",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data.name);
  }
});
```

Or even via `$.getScript()`:

```
$.getScript("path/to/file.js", function( data ) {
  console.log(data.name); 
});
```

Also, you shouldn't need to define the array to a variable.  Would be better as a nested array if you were going to return multiple structures.

```
{ 
  'these_records' : { 
    { 
      "name": "sarah",
      "age": "50" 
    },
    { 
      "name": "mary",
      "age": "40" 
    }
  }
  "other_records": {
    { 
      "name": "bob",
      "age": "50" 
    },
    { 
      "name": "bobert",
      "age": "40" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For the first one I get unexpected token for the last ")"

Comment: Missing a curly bracket.  Try now.